# Conjugate point in some open solid torus

Tags: riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

Note that element in *Heisenberg group* $\mathbb{H}^3$, whose
entries are integers, has the form $$ \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & a_1 & a_3 \\
    0 & 1 & a_2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right),\ a_i\in \mathbb{Z} $$

If $A_i$ is set of such elements s.t. $a_{i+1}=a_{i+2}=0$, then
$A_3$ is a center in a group $$G:=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3,$$ which has an *left isometric action* on $\mathbb{H}^3$.

So $G/A_3$ acts on $X:=\mathbb{H}^3/A_3$. Here
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & a_3 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & x & z \\
    0 & 1 & y \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right) =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & x & z+a_3 \\
    0 & 1 & y \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

Hence $X$ is homeomorphic to an open solid torus. In further note that $X$ is not a product or space form.

**Question** : Does $X$ have no *conjugate point* ?

Here $\mathbb{H}^3$ has a Riemannian metric
$$
g=dx^2 + dz^2 + (x^2+1)dy^2-x\{ dydz +dzdy\}
$$ where $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & x & z \\
    0 & 1 & y \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ is a coordinate parametrization for $\mathbb{H}^3$.

Here $c_1(t)=(0,0,t),\ c_2(t)=(x,y,z+t)$ are two shortest geodesics s.t. they
connect two points in orbits $A_3\cdot (0,0,0),\ A_3\cdot (x,y,z)$,
respectively. And they have same lengths.

So some closed smooth geodesic $c$ in $X$ has closed smooth
geodesics around $c$ of same lengths. Hence the question is true ?

**[Known result]**

(1) $n$-dimensional torus with no conjugate point is flat.

(2) ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ that is homeomorphic to an open solid torus has a conjugate point.

Thank you for your attention.